# valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key imgSelect Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, nsdata, xcode6

Receiving error: valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key imgSelect

I have a tableview with that is editable.. When selecting cell, it takes you to edit information. Everything works great, except the image. User can save image, image is displayed in tableview, but when going back to edit, it crashes. Here is the poorly written code:

without trying to reload the image to edit, everything else works. The image is saved to database and is displayed in tableview..

```
var existingItem: NSManagedObject!

override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()

// Reload data to edit
if existingItem {

    txtPTitle.text = project
    txtPDesc.text = desc
    txtSDate.text = sdate
    txtEDate.text = edate

}
```

but when I add the following to load image when editing tablecell

```
// Reload data back into form
if existingItem {

    txtPTitle.text = project
    txtPDesc.text = desc
    txtSDate.text = sdate
    txtEDate.text = edate

    var data: NSManagedObject = NSManagedObject()
    let imageData:NSData = data.valueForKeyPath("projectImage") as NSData
    let projectImage:UIImage = UIImage(data: imageData)
    println("we have an image")

    imgSelect.image = projectImage
```

}

it crashes with the following error.

```
'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<_NSZeroData 0x7fe7f1c3b020> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key imgSelect.'
```

Comment: Where did you define `imgSelect`? The code would be clearer if you include `self.` when you're referring to your properties. Otherwise it is confusing when others are trying to read it.

Comment: @Rob Napier imSelect is the UIImageView defined in IBOutlet. I apologize for the poor code.

Comment: Can you include your definition of `imgSelect` and information about what class you defined this `var`? Your error is saying that some object of type `NSZeroData` doesn't have a property called `imgSelect`. It's not saying your view controller doesn't have that property, but rather a `NSZeroData` doesn't. That's very curious.

Answer (score 1):

I would suspect that you haven't actually bound `imgSelect` in Interface Builder.

Does it actually crash at the `imgSelect.image = projectImage` line, or perhaps earlier (such as during NIB loading)? Is `imgSelect` correctly? In either beta 4 or beta 5, they changed the way IBOutlets are defined, and you should make sure you've done a complete clean and rebuild since then (otherwise you could wind up with the wrong object, as you're seeing).

Comment: As a matter of fact, imgSelect is bound in IB. Like I said. User can select and save image in form, it is saved to database and when viewing tableview, the image is there.. but, when the user selects cell to edit, the picture is not present. That is the issue.